# Why is this 100% height flex layout going just over 100%?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a flex layout with three rows, total 100% height. The main content should stretch to fill the remaining space. But this code makes the full page use just over 100% of the height.

Here is a minimal example:

```css
html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }

      #container {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
      }

      #main {
        flex: 1;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="main">
        main content
      </div>

      <div>
        footer one
      </div>

      <div>
        footer two
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use `flex-basis` (with `flex-grow`/`flex-shrink`) not `height`, and [learn about how `box-sizing` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: _"trying to make a flex layout with three rows"_ - flexbox is not intended for multi-row layouts (well, multiple-rows with _column-like_ layouts, at least) - is there a reason you're not using `display: grid;` instead?

Comment: @Dai learn how self identification works.

Comment: @Dai I used flex simply because it was what most of the search results talked about when searching for how to create a header, content, footer layout. I'll look at the link you added.

Comment: It appears adding `margin:0` to `body` fixes this.

Comment: @morganney I beg your pardon?

Comment: @Dai apologies, my mistake.